# Multipart upload with urllib3 - value error

Tags: python, urllib3, minio

I'm writing a script to upload a large file (50GB) to our service at work which utilizes minio.

```
config = TransferConfig(multipart_threshold=1024 * 100 * 1024, max_concurrency=10,
                        multipart_chunksize=1024 * 100 * 1024, use_threads=True)

session = boto3.Session(
    aws_access_key_id=upload_data['access_key_id'],
    aws_secret_access_key=upload_data['secret_access_key'],
    aws_session_token=upload_data['session_token'],
    region_name=upload_data['region']
)

client = session.client('s3', endpoint_url='https://maurice-storage.vdoo.team/', verify=False)
client.upload_file(
    image_file,
    upload_data['bucket'],
    upload_data['key'],
    ExtraArgs={'Metadata': {
        'name': os.path.basename(image_file),
        'size': str(os.stat(image_file).st_size),
    }},
    Config = config,
    Callback=ProgressPercentage(image_file)
)
```

I've set the upload to upload chunks of 100 MB (total 500 chunks) as the file is 50GB.

However, once the upload reaches 100%, a ValueError exception is thrown:

```
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\response.py", line 696, in _update_chunk_length
self.chunk_left = int(line, 16)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: b''
```

I **know** why it happens - it tries to call int with an empty binary value (b''), but i'm not sure why that value is there.

Any idea why that could happen?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an issue with the server where after advertising [chunked encoding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Transfer-Encoding) and sending all the chunks, it is not sending the final zero length chunk to indicate the end of the chunked response.

More info [here](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/issues/1516) and especially in this [comment](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/issues/1516#issuecomment-510018712).